# Missing Asian Characters on Android 5.0 Devices

Tags: android, fonts, localization, unity-game-engine, ngui

I'm using Unity4.5.4 and NGUI 3.6, and want to support multi-languages.

When I try on devices using Android 4, it is totally fine. When I install the same build on Google Nexus 7 using Android 5.0, English version is fine, but almost all the Asian characters cannot be displayed(Chinese Korean Japanese). I tried different fonts(using Arial or load my own font from Resource folder), it didn't work either.

Does anybody encounter similar problem, or know how to deal with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the image that you have flashed into your Android device.

> Although the APIs for Android 5.0 are now final, the system image for
>   end-users is not available yet.

Assume everything is done correctly, once the end-user-system images are released your problem should be corrected.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep update when the final version of system released.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Unity. You may want to submit a bug report and wait for a patch release to fix it (though you used a preview image, it is also likely to happen on retail Android 5.0).

Edit: I tried on a Nexus Player, and the fonts were rendering just fine. Looks like Google forgot to add some fonts to the preview image. If you are experiencing this issue with a retail version of Android 5.0, please submit a bug for Unity.